# Pandoc, Markdown to Doc, how to use variables?

Tags: syntax, ms-word, global-variables, markdown, pandoc

AFAIK, variables can be defined in a YAML external file or inside the Markdown file in a header.

Then they can be used in the document. I have found examples with two different sytaxes:

- `$variable$` will convert variable to math mode, which is great (i.e. I want to keep that behaviour).
- `#{variable}` does nothing.

Questions:

- Is it possible to use variables in the pandoc conversion from markdown to .docx?
- If so, how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pandoc variables can only be used in [pandoc templates](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates), not the document itself (there's an [open issue about that](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1950)).

For that you should check out a [preprocessor like `gpp`](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/) or use a pandoc filter like [pandoc-mustache](https://github.com/michaelstepner/pandoc-mustache) or [this lua-filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#replacing-placeholders-with-their-metadata-value).

Comment: I was mistaken, thank you. I don't think gpp will allow me to use variables that are set from the command line, e.g. date (set automatically to whatever date is). So I may try to use instead [Panpipe](https://github.com/Warbo/panpipe), which seems more powerful. I don't have a clear idea of how to use it, so it's going to take a while.